# Deleting a single item from firebase using axios

Tags: javascript, http, firebase, vue.js, axios

Hi there fellow developers,

I would like to ask you, if you could help me with an issue I have not been able to resolve. I have made a very simple TODO List App using Vue.js (I know, very original) and I decided to hook it up to Firebase, so that I don't lose all the data after a page refresh. I was able to fetch data successfuly and also delete all the data (if there is any) but I'm not sure, how to send an http request, when I need to delete one particular item when clicking on it. I was able to do this locally with a simple splice method but I'm not quite sure how it works with Axios/Firebase.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code/repo: https://github.com/tomvorel13/vue-task-manager/blob/master/src/App.vue

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use the Fireabase JavaScript SDK for such interaction between your web client and the Firebase database. This is easier and better than using Axios.

Have a look at the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

and in particular there for learning how to delete an item.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data

It is simply a matter of doing remove() on a reference to the location of that data.

In order to integrate the SDK with a Vue.js application, have a look at these very good tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXY1UyQfSFw&list=PL55RiY5tL51qxUbODJG9cgrsVd7ZHbPrt and in particular videos #13 and following for the Firebase part.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a look.